# 'max_length' must be a positive integer

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

is there any way to figure out what file this error regard?

```
serverad@ubuntu:~/django14_project/my_django15_project$ python manage.py runserver --traceback --settings=settings -v 3
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fc853a639b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 405, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
events.SystemLog.text: (fields.E121) 'max_length' must be a positive integer.
events.SystemLog.type: (fields.E121) 'max_length' must be a positive integer.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

Here is the System log module that our last programmer left behind

```
class SystemLog(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='log_actions')
chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, null=True, blank=True, default=None, 
related_name="logs")
affected = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='log_entries', null=True, 
blank=True)
type = models.CharField(max_length='20')
text = models.CharField(max_length='100')
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_personal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Provide your models.py file.Seems there is some issue with your model

Comment: please update your question to  include your models.py file : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a regex search in something like notepad++ or pycharm

```
max_length=[^\d]
```

In terms of your current position you have two strings

```
type =  models.CharField(max_length='20')
text = models.CharField(max_length='100')
```

should be:

```
type =  models.CharField(max_length=20)
text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Actually error says that his max_length may not be an integer at all - so regexp should be more like max_length=.*

Comment: @Sayse  Changed it as you said but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @EthanBaxter - Quite possibly there are migration files that have been erroneously created as well... hence the regex search

Comment: @Sayse I was in the wrong module file. It almost works now. now it says  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have included in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` the application `events`, which defines the model `SystemLog`.

This model has the field `text` and the field `type` whose definition includes the keyword `max_length` with a value which is not a positive integer.

If you use Eclipse/PyDev, you could press `Ctrl`+ `Shift` + `R` and type `SystemLog` to find that class.

**EDIT**

Given the actual model, `max_length` was given a string and not an integer...

Comment: I have updated the question to have the SystemLog module in it. I have just gotten this code from our old programmer so I have no idea what he did.